# Android Studio 3.2 gradle sync button gone

Tags: android-studio

Up to the previous version of Android Studio there was a button to manually perform a gradle sync, I can't find it on Android Studio 3.2 though. It used to be here:

[image]

Is it really gone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]Still there, it's the third button on the toolbar from the left.